# Residue of $f^2$ using $f$ Laurent coefficients

Tags: residue-calculus

I need help with the following: 
If $f$ is a function having $z_0$ as a second order Pole. and having the Laurent series $\sum_{k = - \infty}^{\infty} a_k (z-z_0)^k$. How could one calculate $Res_{z_0} f^2$ from the Laurent coefficients $a_k$ of $f$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: the laurent series of $f$ can be written as
 $ \frac{a_{-2}}{(z-z0)^2} + \frac{a_{-1}}{(z-z0)} + a_0 + \dots$ 
 then I thought about doing the square and looking for the new $a_1$. The multiplication seems a bit difficult to me.

Comment: You only need the new minus one term.

Answer (score 0):

Write $f(z)=\sum_{k=-2}^{\infty}a_k(z-z_0)^k$.Multiply and get for the residue of $f^2$:   $$c_{-1}=\sum_{i+j=-1}a_ia_j=2a_{-2}a_1+2a_{-1}a_0$$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just need to check where $(z-z_0)^-1$ remains after the multiplication.